# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user with some calls in my project and every call belongs to one user. I have used laravel elequent relationships to retrive a user calls as following:
user model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';

    public function customer_logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\call_log');
    }
```

call model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class call_log extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customer_logs';

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

but when I call customer_logs function in my controller I face this error:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$customer_logs

this my controller:

```
$user = User::first()->get();
        $user->customer_logs->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using first so there is no need to call get on your query. Change it to

```
$user = User::first(); 
$user->customer_logs()
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help. it works for first() but what about where? User::where('number',$phone)->get()

Comment: Can you vote or accept the answer. With get it will return a collection/array of items so you have to loop through the collection. foreach($users as $usr){ logic/code goes here}

Comment: If you want only one record you can changed the get to first